# Create function that loops through an array to produce multiple rows of set width

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I hope I titled my question correctly.

I am attempting to build a function which will parse through an array in groups of four and then print those groups of four in a row. Ideally when done, it would look like the [gallery of images](http://max-o-matic.com/template.php) as shown here in my prior iteration. In that attempt I built a function that called each row separately – now I’m trying to do it with a `for` loop inside a `for` loop. Maybe it would be better as a `foreach` loop inside a `foreach` loop, I don’t know.

Currently, I’m getting the following error: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare PrintFolio() (previously declared in htdocs//05a_03/_inc/functions.php:42) in htdocs/05a_03/_inc/functions.php on line 42`

Line #42 reads as follows: `function PrintFolio($arrayEntered)//begin function)`

Here is my function as currently written:

```
function PrintFolio($aaPlaceholder)
{ //loop through array of X items, for each group of 4 print as a row

for($row = 0; $row <= height; $row++)//looping thru rows
        {
            echo '<div class="row flush">'; //open div
            for($image = 0; $image <= 3; $image++)//print 4 images
            {
                echo '<div class="3u"><a href="_img/fulls/$key" 
                class="image full"><img src="_img/thumbs/$key" 
                alt="" title="$value" /></a></div>';// echo image
            }

            echo '</div>'; //end div group of 4
        }//end loop
    }//end function
```

Comment: It is obvious that you have a previously defined function with the same name. Try changing the function's name.

Comment: No, actually I don't have two functions with the same name. I have the old function which is called 'PrintPortfolio3' and then i have the new attempted function which is named 'function PrintFolio'. However i did just comment out the old function to see what that would do and i get a new error (syntax error, unexpected '}' in...). So thank you for the help.

Comment: The error is telling you that you have created two functions of the same name

Comment: After commenting out the a similarly named function (PrintPortfolio3), i got some new errors and found that i had some code that was not correctly commented out at the bottom of my function file - I'm dyslexic and make mistakes. Once I corrected the commenting tags, I moved to a completely new error so i guess this is resolved although my problems persist which is cool.

Comment: Thank you SyntaxLAMP (Neat handle), i get that now. But i wish i understood why as i didn't have two functions with the same name. I thought, and maybe wrongly so, that you could name a function newFunction and newFUNction (the difference being only the casing/formatting of the name) and that would count as two different functions - not that i would ever do that as that be beyond confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I had a function with a similar name 'PrintPortfolio3' and 'PrintFolio'. When i commented out PrintPortfolio3, my fatal errors cleared up and I got to some more workable errors. I don't understand why php sees PrintPortfolio3 and PrintFolio as being the same function as they call different arrays and are named differently, but it seems to have been the issue and one i'll be asking my teachers more about today as it's quite odd to me. Thanks to those who helped.